# How to limit the maximum number of threads snow can start in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am using the snow package for parallel computing in R, even though I only initialized 8 workers (`cl = makeCluster(rep('localhost', 8), 'SOCK')`), many threads of `R --slave --no-restore` can be seen in the process monitor, how can I limit the number of threads?

Comment: Yes, call `stopCluster` like `?makeCluster` suggests you do.

Comment: snow will start exactly 8 processes in your example.  We can't really tell where those other processes or threads are coming from, although @JoshuaUlrich may be correct that they are left over from previous calls to `makeCluster` that weren't shutdown, but it's impossible to know unless you tell us more about what you're doing.